# Force gpg to use compression?

Tags: compression, gnupg

Odd situation, and I won't go into details about why our present circumstances require it.  But, I'm looking for a way to force gpg to use compression.  My testing is suggesting that the following command ignores the '-z' option:

```
gpg -z 6 -e test.zip
```

Note that the object to be encrypted is a zip archive.  I'm using the bouncycastle java library to crack open output blob and it doesn't appear to be using pgp-compression.

My suspicion is that gpg detects that the file to be encrypted is already compressed and doesn't re-compress it.  Unfortunately that's precisely what I need it to do.

Can anyone confirm this is the case (gpg doesn't re-compress)?  And if so, is there a way to force it?  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to compress an already compressed file.  The results may result in a file significantly larger than the original!

Comment: Agreed - it is a silly thing to need.  But I need it :)

Comment: Using `-v` with your command shows your suggest is right; neither the man page nor the [esoteric options manual](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/GPG-Esoteric-Options.html#fnd-1) know anything about enforcing compression of compressed contents. Probably you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the relevant source file ([encode.c](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=g10/encode.c;h=a579c428d43de599ad073824da7052f780a65ee9;hb=refs/heads/STABLE-BRANCH-1-4); search for `is_file_compressed`), GPG will still do the compression if MDC is disabled. So passing `--disable-mdc` should do the trick.

If you don't want to disable MDC, then you should probably compile your own copy of GPG with the compression check removed.